# Sort a Single Column in Ascending or Descending Order using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to sort the following price columns within a text file using Perl.

```
Time    Num    Size     Price Act | Act Price   Size    Num       Time  
11:30:12.957    1   3000 11.90  A  |  A  11.05   500     1      11:30:12.954   
11:30:12.957    1   100  11.75  A  |  A  14.00   1676    3      11:30:12.957
```

I can read the text file into an array and sort it fine by row but I cannot think of how to sort a specific column in *Ascending* or *Descending* order?
Tried reading in the text file one element at a time as follows to start with and then attempting to sort the first `Price` Column in descending order

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $file_handle, '<', 'Data.txt') or die("Error: File cannot be opend:  $!");

my @words;

while (<$file_handle>) {
chomp;
@words = split(' ');
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "sort a column", or "sort the rows *by* a column"?

Comment: I was attempting to sort a column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $file_handle, '<', 'Data.txt') or die("Error: File cannot be opend:  $!");

my @rows;

while (<$file_handle>) {
  $. > 1 or next; # skip header line
  chomp;
  push @rows, [ split ]; # split current line on \s+ 
}

# sort descending on 4-th column
@rows = sort { $b->[3] <=> $a->[3] } @rows;

# ascending sort on same column
# @rows = sort { $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] } @rows;
```

Comment: If I try to print out the contents of the @rows using a for loop as shown: for(my $i = 0; $i <= $#rows; $i++){
 print $rows[$i] . "\n";
 } - I get the memory location ARRAY(0x966bac) - Do you know how I can get the actual values?